# Как поверх заблокированного экрана выводить информацию?

Tags: android

Я бы хотел написать кастомные часы, которые бы отображались как и системные поверх заблокированного экрана. Кто знает как это возможно сделать? У меня есть небольшой опыт разработки, т.е. беспокоит только заблокированный экран.

Comment: разве это не лучше сделать виджетом?

Comment: да, я хотел сделать виджетом, но как его выводить поверх или на LockScreen-е?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть чем-нибудь поможет:
[тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget) Там есть ссылка на код проекта.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я тоже это уже смотрел. Вкратце для читающих топик: можно создать активити, которая будет при нажатии на "power" отображаться вместо ЛокСкрина(если ваше приложение с этой активити запущено). Аналогичный виджет создать нельзя. На днях буду изучать исходники кастомного ЛокСкрина. Если что обнаружится интересное - отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю на не рутовоном девайсе это можно сделать только обновлением обоев экрана блокировки. Буду рад если это не так.

Comment: Что означает изменение обоев экрана блокировки? Нужно перехватывать блокировку экрана и изменять обои на те которые будут содержать необходимую информацию?

Comment: нет. Есть настройка обоев экрана блокировки. Попозже напишу как кодом это делать. Надо написать сервис который будет с какой то периодичностью менять эти обои на нужные свои (взяли старые обои, нарисовали на них что надо, выставили) - т.е. живых элементов на экран блокировки не получиться добавить только инфу

Comment: Если можете выложить как это сделать кодом - буду ждать вместе с читателями топика. Спасибо